# remove blue shadow of NSButton

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton

Always (programmatically or via IB) i get this blue shadow on the first set button:

[image: blue shadow]

I want to get rid of it.. how?

Comment: What do you mean by Blue shadow? Did u mean the title color?

Comment: Note that by removing the focus ring you’re also removing the system feedback of which view currently receives keyboard events. If you do that, consider providing an alternative indication.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's called the focus ring, and it's to visually indicate which view is the first responder for key events.

If you don't want it to show up, you can use the [`-[NSView setFocusRingType:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000014-BBCJHACC) method with the `NSFocusRingTypeNone` constant.  This is also settable in Interface Builder.

Comment: This effectively hides the blue ring, but do you know of any way to actually prevent the button from getting focus? I don't want the space bar to trigger my buttons, but one of them has grabbed focus.

Answer (score 1):

This is to-do with the how the computer accesses windows via the keyboard. The highlight is notifying the user that this is the currently focused control.

To remove it from that control simply

`[someOtherControl becomeFirstResponder];`

Read more:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextEditing/Tasks/SetFocus.html

Comment: Try `[theWindow makeFirstResponder: anotherControl];`

Comment: Sorry, I think its meant to be `[[self window] makeFirstResponder:[self window]]`